# Identityserver3 how to log out from external login provider?

Tags: identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer3 in combination with multiple login providers. Login works without any problem. Logging a user out leads to some troubles though.

When I log out I'm not really logged out from e.g. google. This means that when I login again using IdentityServer3 I don't need to provide username/password to google.I believe this is a known issue and others have posted questions about this. Fortunately, I can always log out from google in my browser using google's web-site.

However, I'm also developing a chrome extension. The chrome extension does not get logged out when I log out from Google's web-site. I'm also developing an android app. Logging out also doesn't work here. For both systems, this effectively means that I'm unable to perform a real logout.

What is the proposed way to logout, such that during the next login the login provider will display a username/password entries? This is also needed in order to be able to switch user.

Thanks in advance for your help!

I read and understood how to enable logging
Question / Issue

Relevant parts of the log file

Comment: Logging out only really makes sense for browser-based apps, no?

Comment: @BrockAllen in my case certainly certainly not! So the question remains how to do this properly with IdentityServer3?

Comment: For a mobile app, you are most likely using an embedded browser (at least until more modern mobile OSs do better job with the shared system browsers). So what does it mean to logout? Well, it means your client app just throws away its tokens, right? The only reason to visit the token service to signout is if you want to have some server side code invoked.

I guess I'm just trying to determine the requirement based on my above question. What does signing out mean for your scenario?

Comment: I.m indeed using an embedded browser. I want to achieve that after a user logs out from my app, the next time he starts the app he has to select a loginprovider on the login page of IdentityServer3 and then he is redirected to the login page of the selected external login 
provider _and_ then requested to fill in his username/password. The current situation is that the user is still logged in at the external login provider. As a result, when the user is redirected to the external login provider the login provider directly redirects him to my app and no username/password need to be entered.

Comment: This means that after I logged in on my app through an external login provider like Google, even after logging out through IdentityServer3 anyone else can still log in under my identity on my app from this device because no credentials are needed. As another consequence, I can't support changing users in my app because the login system will always use my identity. At least I don't know how to do this. Similar situation exists when trying to logout from a browser extension.

Comment: @BrockAllen Is the use case with the above information clear to yo now? Any suggestions about how to properly sign out from external providers?

Comment: For your browser plug-in, the only way I can think to know when the user has signed out is to use the JS-based approach.

Comment: @BrockAllen what do you mean by "JS-based apprach". Do you have a pointer to some info? Do you agree it is a use case that IdentityServer should address?

Comment: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout-session.html